# JQuery data-attribute is undefined on change of a select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu, custom-data-attribute

I try to create options and after set data of jQuery object dynamically in a select with this mode but not work.

This is my HTML code for print shops options and give it a `data-attribute` called "data-last-sync-shop"

```
<select id="shopSelect" 
        onchange="$('#lastSync').text($(this).data('lastSyncShop'));" 
        name="shop_select">

    <option value=""></option>

    <?php foreach ($shops as $code => $info) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $code ?>" 
                data-last-sync-shop="<?= $info['last_sync'] ?>">
            <?= $info['description'] ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<span id="lastSync">-</span>
```

If i debug the `onchange` event of select the data-attribute is **undefined** but if I inspect the HTML code generated by PHP the data-attribute of the options are correctly populate. Why? Where is my wrong? Thanks for answers.

I add `console.log()` as here:

```
<select id="shopSelect" 
        onchange="console.log($(this).data('lastSyncShop'));" <!-- undefined --> 
        name="filtro[codice_shop_select]">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to target the [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) `option` element.

```
 $(this).find('option:selected').data('lastSyncShop')
```